# navigation bar links move when hover

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, move

In my html page I have the following for the hover action on the navigation links.

```
<td class="menuNormal"
    onmouseover="expand(this);"
    onmouseout="collapse(this);"
    width="130"
    align="left">
  <p><b>Vida de Mulher</b></p>
  <div class="menuNormal">
    <table class="menu" width="130">
      <tr>
        <!-- ... -->
```

And this is the css style sheet which is used for the hover action:

```
table.navbar {
    font-size: 12pt;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px; 
    border: 0px; 
}

table.menu {
    font-size: 11pt;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
}

td.menuNormal {
    padding: 0px;
    color: #003399;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

td.menuHover {
    padding: 0px;
    color: #003399;
    width: 112px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: what is your question and what is your goal here?

Comment: Please be more specific.................

Comment: Can we also see a larger snippet of your code and can you confirm if you are using JQuery and if so what version?

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by a `:hover` effect in your css, or maybe removing the width of your td class `.menuNormal` in your html code will remove this moving effect, in last case if none of these works I suggest adding the same width to `td.menuHover` assuming this class was created for some hover effect on your `td`

```
td.menuHover {
    padding: 0px;
    color: #003399;
    width: 130px; /* changing this value for the same as .menuNormal */
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```